# Can a woman help a blind man to cross the road?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, sunnah

Can a woman help a blind non mahram man to cross the road by holding his hand?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I kiss or hug my friend's wife who is like a sister to me?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/51044/can-i-kiss-or-hug-my-friends-wife-who-is-like-a-sister-to-me)

Answer (score -1):

by holding his hand no because we have hadeth in it
but to help him to cross the road by holding his crutch or by making him holding your bag yes she can help him

Comment: ...I think the hadith refers to man/women touching the opposite sex inappropriately or in the name of lust, as also commented on by Dr Yasir Qadihi. If women or man can't touch the opposite sex then I don't think even doctors can operate or examine on their opposite sex properly, cuz they are not meant to touch. I guess, if the touch is appropriate and not based on lust or desire then it should be okay.

Comment: @EPICTubeHD One's personal opinions and thoughts do not have any weight in Islamic law. Nor are preachers qualified to give verdicts, and being involved in apologetics they are rather susceptible to molding or misrepresenting Islam. It is well known that there is an allowance for non-mahram doctors to see and touch a non-mahram when there is a need and no alternative is available. Something being permitted during a time of need does not mean that it is also permitted without that need, just like permission to eat pork in starvation does not mean that it is permitted to eat pork in general.

Comment: So is it permissable or not ?

Comment: @UmH the comment I posted isn't personal but rather provided and discussed by other scholars too. I do have to disagree and agree at the same time about your statement that "opinions" (not personal) and "thoughts" don't weight in Islamic law. You do know that a lot of scholars in Islam and within the 4 schools of thought have a difference in opinion and they have devised laws upon those "opinions". Secondly, these preachers especially the one I mentioned, certainly is qualified in their knowledge of Islam hence can provide legitimite explainations. Maybe not verdicts, cuz they aint muftis.

Comment: As for, the question by the OP, he/she makes a specific situation. A situation where a blind man is trying to cross the street. Me as a Muslim guy, walking past say blind women asking ppl to help her cross the street and no one helping her... I can't ignore. A similar situation goes for say a non-mahram woman who gets mugged or says gets into an accident...I can't avoid that, but instead, rush to help. I won't be restricted to not help a non-mahram out when the ruling on touching women, even without any desire is opinionated.

Comment: @UmH Although I do condone the fact that unnecessarily touching woman is not okay since the sunnah is to avoid from any touching with women in the first place, becuz that what our prophet (SAW); man of ultimate modesty did)and we are supposed to follow his examples.