# Can I hug my girlfriend?

Tags: halal-haram

My girlfriend wants to give me a hug and neither of us are married or anything could I hug her back or not? My girlfriend is not muslim and she is able to hug me. Would it be Haram if I was to hug her?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I kiss or hug my friend's wife who is like a sister to me?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/51044/can-i-kiss-or-hug-my-friends-wife-who-is-like-a-sister-to-me)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hug or even touch your girl friend before marriage, it is forbidden (haram).

> Say, "**My Lord has only forbidden immoralities - what is apparent of
> them and what is concealed -** and sin, and oppression without right,
> and that you associate with Allah that for which He has not sent down
> authority, and that you say about Allah that which you do not know." https://legacy.quran.com/7/33

We should do our best to avoid doing haram things. But we are humans and may do some haram things and the remedy for this is to do good deeds to compensate for the haram things.

> A man kissed a woman and then came to Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) and told
> him of that, so this Divine Inspiration was revealed to the Prophet
> (ﷺ) 'And offer Prayers perfectly at the two ends of the day, and in
> some hours of the night; (i.e. (five) compulsory prayers). Verily, the
> good deeds remove the evil deeds (small sins) That is a reminder for
> the mindful.' (11.114) The man said, Is this instruction for me only?'
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "It is for all those of my followers who
> encounter a similar situation." https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4687

Answer (score 0):

AssalamuAlaykum. In addressing your question, it's important to note that in Islam, physical contact between individuals of the opposite gender who are not related is generally discouraged. This includes actions such as hugging. This rule is in place to prevent potential pitfalls that could lead to undesirable outcomes. While your girlfriend may not be a Muslim and may feel comfortable hugging you, as a Muslim, it is encouraged for you to uphold the teachings of your faith. Remember, Islam encourages modesty and respect in all interactions. If you find yourself in an unsure situation, it may be best to kindly and respectfully explain your religious beliefs to your girlfriend.